# C# Compile OutOfMemory error while I'm trying to dynamically generate file manipulating codes to be compiled

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, out-of-memory

Straight to the point,
**I'm trying to write a program that encapsulates the bytes from some big files into the executable file (.exe).
Then those files can be installed back by executing that exe file.**

I started from the stupidest method (**Dynamically generating codes to be compiled**)

1. Read the byte arrays from the target files into program.
2. Dynamically generate codes that can be compiled later, and the codes are about
   to init and write those byte arrays on the disk. (So it's very hard byte array initiating code such as: **byte[] file = new byte[25, 122, 16, 38, 54, .....]** generated according to the file.)
3. Programmatically use C# compiler to compile those codes.
4. Get the output executable.

Here's my generated code for example:

```
byte[] Fningjpg = new byte[]{ 255,216,255,224,54,26,199,224,135,253,22,79,135,2........very very long]
File.WriteAllBytes(@"ning.jpg",Fningjpg);
Console.WriteLine("Fningjpg bytes length: "+Fningjpg.Length);
Fningjpg= null;
System.GC.Collect();
```

Despite its bad efficiency, it works very well in medium size files.

**OutOfMemory** Error occurs while I'm **compiling** the codes that trying to encapsulate the big file (30MB), which has a very very long byte array declaration code.

Any better way to meet this requirement? Thanks! (My files would only have at most 
 to 100 mb! Solution for this size is enough!)

Comment: Every Setup programm on the planet has the ability to store the data effectively (some layer of compression). Rolling it all into one file is a really bad practice. Out of propably hundreds of installers, I only saw one that put it all into one file. This ran head first into the UAC, wich at worst has to scan the full file before it can even ask for elevation. The other cases where one file was needed, a Self Extracting .zip, .rar or .7zip file was usually used. The Self Extraction usually allows to order a programm (like a setup.exe) to be started afterwards.

Comment: @Christopher: It is common practice to distribute a single exe containing the installer and the data (especially for internet downloads). However, coding this oneself sounds like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @PMF: I did mention the self-extracting Archive Option. Specialized installation ways (like most Appstores and ClickOnce) might have their own way to pack it all into one file. But they also deal with all the side issues (like the UAC) arising from that pattern.

Comment: thanks a lot! I would go have a study on some compression methods, self-extracting as well!

Comment: I have applied the built-in compression library for getting compressed/decompressed bytes, finally turns out no error occurs again during compilation. (though it's a very hard code, but still fun. thanks for giving direction).